# Change login cookie expiration time?

Tags: customization

Is it possible to change the expiration time of the logged in cookie? Right now I have to login again from time to time. But I want to extend this time to be much longer, maybe infinite.

The thing is I have created pages on the frontend that requires you to be logged in, and I don't want the user to have to login again.

Is it possible to set the login expiration for frontend to never expire? Or maybe both?

Answer (score 0):

Since Wordpress 2.8 a filter is provided to set the cookie expiration .

```
apply_filters( 'auth_cookie_expiration', int $length, int $user_id, bool $remember )
```

More details [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/auth_cookie_expiration/)